# How to instantiate polymer component programmatically in dartlang?

Tags: dart, instantiation, polymer

I have a question about polymer in dartlang.

How to instantiate polymer component programmatically in dartlang and of course add it to the dom?

I have an example for web_ui which works:

```
RedBorderComponent wc = new RedBorderComponent()..host = new DivElement();
ComponentItem lifecycleCaller = new ComponentItem(wc)..create();
content.children.add(wc.host);
```

Comment: Yes, looks like a dupe. Not sure how to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

From the provided link:

Here is the example code:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

main() {
  query('#add-here').children.add(createElement('my-element'));
}
```

Notice the use of `createElement('my-element')`.

Comment: This is (no longer) correct. Refer to the duplicate question link above if you're looking for an up-to-date answer.